# Windows Event-5152 happens during WCF program is GC and the WCF stops serving

Tags: c#, windows, wcf, garbage-collection, event-log

I have a .Net 4.0 WCF program which host in Windows service.

The program uses about 40GB of memory.

I found that there was no WCF call during the GC Time.

The GC lasts about 60 seconds.

In the Event log, I found a lot of [Event-5152](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/event-5152)(The Windows Filtering Platform blocked a packet) during that time.

But, interestingly, another program which runs in the same way (and uses about 20GB of memory) doesn't have this problem.

Both programs have no config for GC.  (It should be workstation GC).

I'm wondering what causes Event-5152. Is it GC or other things?  Or should I restore Windows?

**Additon1:** Yes, I cache billions of data in memory, don't doubt it. It was designed mony years ago.

Comment: Even for task manager 20-40 gigs is excessive.Use a memory profiler to figure out what nasty leaky code you have built :)

Comment: 40GB seems to be very large, you need to check for memory leaks inside your application.

Comment: 40 GB -- Are you caching data in this WCF?

Answer (score 1):

Event 5152 are general Windows Firewall security audit.The reason this is happening is that the firewall was most likely disabled in the services control panel. Just ENABLING WINDOWS FIREWALL will immediately stop the blocking experienced as long as the firewall rules are set accordingly to allow/disallow traffic.

Comment: I think you get it. The firewall was stoped. I have restarted it and see what's going on.

Comment: No. You are wrong. It does't work. The reason should be GC. I will config it when it got restarted next time.